# Touch screen not recognize by Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, xorg, touchscreen, input

I have a Lenovo C315 10038:

after install Ubuntu 13.04 64bits i've installed

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-*
```

and nothing

this is the infor  from `lsusb`, `lspci`, `xinput` commands

### `xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo USB2.0 UVC Camera                  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

### `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0ac8:c412 Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ac8:c41e Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4d80 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0ac8:c41e Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

### `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Graphics Port 0)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 7914
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 1)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
08:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
08:00.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
08:00.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
08:00.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
```

Comment: What's your kernel version?